# When I going to deploy my react native expo app. I get this error

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, file-upload, expo

error :

`[stderr]  > 29 | import awsconfig from '../../src/aws-exports';`

please help me

I used aws for upl;oad my images .

this is the expo site

[image: 1]

this error

[image: 2]

Comment: Could you post the entire error please?

Comment: I added a image. there is no error when i use expo go . but this error come when im going to deploy to expo